# Return method with parameters to execute in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to return a method with parameters in Ruby to execute later.

What I tried is this one:

```rb
def my_method(a, b)
    p a
    p b
end

def action
    return "my_method", ["A", "B"]
end

method, pars = action
send(method, *pars)
```

Which is actually working, but what is, if the parameters of "my_method" are complex structures, and not just strings ot whatever, so I can't put them as strings to an array of parameters.
So maybe there is just a more elegant way to solve this?
So any chance to do something like `return my_method(a,b)` without executing it but realy returning for later processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lambdas, if you return a lambda you just need to execute `.call` later.

```rb
def my_method(a, b)
  p a
  p b
end

def action
 -> { my_method("A", "B") }
end

method, pars = action
action.call
```

Comment: Why not just `action = -> { my_method("A", "B") }`? Also, It needn't necessarily be a lambda; it could be a simple proc.

Comment: @CarySwoveland +...or a `Method`. Depending on application you can use e.g. `action = method(:my_method)` and later `action["A","B"]` or even `action = method(:my_method).curry["A"]` and later `action["B"]` all of which will result in the same output.